# ExceptionInInitializerError when instanciating AsyncTask inside Plugin.execute()

Tags: android, plugins, android-asynctask, cordova-2.0.0

im developping an app and inside it i'm using `cordova` Api to communicate between *`Sencha`* code and `*Android native Code*`.

inside my plugin's `execute` method , i'm launching an `AsyncTask`( for device registration) , but i got `ExceptionInInitializerError` in ***line 36*** ( instanciation of `TaskDeviceRegistration`).

**RegistrationDevicePlugin** :

```
public class DeviceRegistrationPlugin extends Plugin {

    public static final String TAG = "DeviceRegistrationPlugin";
    public static final String ACTION_REGISTER_DEVICE = "registerDeviceAction";

    protected String callBackMethod;

    @Override
    public PluginResult execute(String action, JSONArray args, String callBackId) {

        String token;
        if(action.equals(ACTION_REGISTER_DEVICE)) {
            try {
                token = args.getString(0);
                if(token != null) {
                    // launch the task to register device
                    SharedPreferences prefs = cordova.getActivity().getSharedPreferences(WebServiceRequest.PREFS_IDENTIFICATION, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    prefs.edit().putString(WebServiceRequest.PREF_TOKEN_PARAM, token).commit();
                    TaskRegisterDevice task = new TaskRegisterDevice(cordova.getActivity());// this is the line 36
                    task.execute();

                    // tell the plugin that the callBack will be executed after the task
                    // has finished his work.
                    this.callBackMethod = callBackId;
                    PluginResult pluginResult = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.NO_RESULT);
                    pluginResult.setKeepCallback(true);
                    return pluginResult;
                }
                else {
                    return new PluginResult(Status.ERROR, "token required");
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.JSON_EXCEPTION);
            }
        }
        else {
            // invalid action sended to the plugin
            return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.INVALID_ACTION);
        }
    }


    /**
     * asynctask to register the device
     * @author houcine
     * 
     */
    class TaskRegisterDevice extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

        protected Context context;

        public TaskRegisterDevice(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                return WebServiceRequest.RegisterDevice(context);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return true;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            // return new plugin result when synchronization done
            Log.d(TAG, "resultat DeviceRegistration : "+result + " , \ncallBackMethod : "+callBackMethod);
            PluginResult pluginResult = new PluginResult(
                    PluginResult.Status.OK, result);
            pluginResult.setKeepCallback(false);
            success(pluginResult, callBackMethod);
        }

    }

}
```

**ManifestFile :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myapp.activity"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0.2" >

     <supports-screens
     android:largeScreens="true"
     android:normalScreens="true"
     android:smallScreens="true"
     android:resizeable="true"
     android:anyDensity="true"
     />

     <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="5" android:targetSdkVersion="16"/>
     //other stuff : declaration of <application> tag , activities , services...etc
>
```

**and logCat  :**

```
01-01 06:54:26.251: E/AndroidRuntime(6189): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-31
01-01 06:54:26.251: E/AndroidRuntime(6189): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
01-01 06:54:26.251: E/AndroidRuntime(6189):     at com.myapp.plugins.DeviceRegistrationPlugin.execute(DeviceRegistrationPlugin.java:36)
01-01 06:54:26.251: E/AndroidRuntime(6189):     at org.apache.cordova.api.PluginManager$1.run(PluginManager.java:192)
01-01 06:54:26.251: E/AndroidRuntime(6189):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
01-01 06:54:26.251: E/AndroidRuntime(6189): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
01-01 06:54:26.251: E/AndroidRuntime(6189):     at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
01-01 06:54:26.251: E/AndroidRuntime(6189):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.<init>(AsyncTask.java:421)
01-01 06:54:26.251: E/AndroidRuntime(6189):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.<init>(AsyncTask.java:421)
01-01 06:54:26.251: E/AndroidRuntime(6189):     at android.os.AsyncTask.<clinit>(AsyncTask.java:152)
01-01 06:54:26.251: E/AndroidRuntime(6189):     ... 3 more
```

**NOTE : the app is working just fine on HTC ONE S , HTC ONE X , SAMSUNG GALAXY S II , SAMSUNG GALAXY SIII with android sdk version : 4.0 or higher , but it doesn't work for devices with android version like : 2.2.2 , 2.3.5 , 2.3.3**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`AsyncTask` should be created and executed on the UI thread. It looks like `DeviceRegistrationPlugin.execute()` method is invoked outside the main thread that's why you are getting the error.

You can try to fix it this way:

```
cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        TaskRegisterDevice task = new TaskRegisterDevice(cordova.getActivity());
        task.execute();
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for the reply , but how do explain that the code is working 100% fine on android 4.0 or higher , but for android 2.3.3 ,  2.2.2 , 2.3.5 ,  2.3.6 is not ?

Comment: According to `AsyncTask` documentation `The AsyncTask class must be loaded on the UI thread. This is done automatically as of JELLY_BEAN`. I think this is the explanation.

Comment: i know ,but i've tested it on ICS and it works too . ok i will make some changes of logic and force it to run on the UIThread to avoid this issue. thanks :)